# How does typescript narrow generics？

Tags: typescript

I wrote the following code, but an error occurred with the return value

```js
function test_fn<T> (arg: T): T extends string | number ? boolean : number
{
    if(typeof arg === "string" || typeof arg === "number")
    {
        return true
    }
    return 1
}
```

The error message is：
TS2322: Type 'true' is not assignable to type 'T extends string | number ? boolean : number'.

[image]

I feel like my writing should get the type inference right, but it doesn't. What can I do to eliminate this type error?

Comment: Maybe the problem is that your type guard narrows type of `arg` to `(T & string) | (T & number)` instead of to `string | number`?

Comment: Maybe related: https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/33014

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Please check the below code snippet which resolves the above issue.

```js
type TestFnReturnType = boolean | number

function test_fn<T> (arg: T): TestFnReturnType 
{
    if(typeof arg === "string" || typeof arg === "number")
    {
        return true
    }
    return 1
}
```

My implementation simply neglects if the type of T is a number. Maybe you can convert the number into a string and use it if it is required.

Comment: This answer does not seem to solve the main problem, I simplified the code for the problem, you can check it out

Comment: Hey @Autumn., https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/CYUwxgNghgTiAEYD2A7AzgF0VCYBc8AFCAB4AOMBmMAligOYA08SZGNqaA-AVCgJ4BKeAF4AfPD78A3AChZGfmQQBlDDADyMAHIBXALaj41OvXgAfeCgMAjEDDkKlCAMI4wAdRhQyAJRAYujAoACrORmqaOgYWRMTklPCRWnr6wuJJ6ikGwpbWEBDyAGa6KGDsqNi4APoA7t5kADwh8KQYICjAaPClANYoSLUoYvEU1Ugw1cBQGFAEIczTszySAoIEbrhePv6BwWHK8ADesvBniJxY1UU0BVMzc6v8ANoAukZvcucX6FisFegjEd4NV7DAJgQAETVSHwAC+jm+NCKhEUyiQRVaCXGkyWUFEIhE8AA5CYGMThCdvt84HsUFUwIQsWMJvdZswqdSuddbhA2VBGKcudSAHRi-4cdBCrlw+DCKDdZLRfRfc5w060oL0tEgDHMyasvEEomk9SmYnwLhEfUEJWpOW2rLK0QSMDuJmkCiSbpkpggm53I3CAj5CBydVAA.

Comment: I have executed the code at the above playground and it is working fine.

Comment: For the simplified code https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/FAFwngDgpgBAKlAziAYgOwEpRAVwE5pySwC8MARgPaUA2UAhmjAD4xo4C25UewwAZjjQBjEAEtKTEEhAB9fmgA8cAHwwAFPTwBzAFzwAlPoTJ0WXASLQYwAN7AYjmGP7rw0SvxhbtMEv5gAImQ8MTRtQJZWdyhPbx0-AMD2Lh5AgwcneyccmDxsfCk8HChMxwBfMryCghgARmBKoA

Comment: With similar approaches, both of them are working fine. Not sure why it is not working at your end.

Comment: Sorry, I made a mistake. This is really a way to solve the problem

Comment: Thanks, @Autumn. Unfortunately, I can see downvotes. If it solves the problem, could you kindly upvote & accept the answer?

Comment: Im guessing the downvotes are because the return type is no longer `true` when the input was a `string` or `number`, it's _always_ `true | number`. So while it may solve OPs problem sufficiently, the original code was string to do something more. `arg` might as well be `any` now.

Answer (score 0):

Here's an alternative solution that solves the problem as well, and has the additional property that if the input *was* a string or number, it also correctly figures out that the return type is always `true`.

```js
function test_fn(arg: string|number): true; 
function test_fn(arg: unknown): number; 
function test_fn(arg: string|number|unknown): true | number {

  if(typeof arg === "string" || typeof arg === "number") {
    return true;
  }
  return 1;
}


const foo = test_fn(5); // inferred as true
const bar = test_fn('hi'); // inferred as true
const zim = test_fn(true); // inferred as number
```